# No Solution Is Working. Bone Heat Weighting Failure. I've Tried Everything

Tags: armature, bones

I have a crab that I'm trying to connect to an armature and nothing is working. I have no non-manifold, no corner doubles, I tried separating and rejoining and I also tried re-scaling my mesh.

[image: crab with armature]

[image: crab bone pop out]

Comment: Also, Does it matter if a side of a bone is popping out of the mesh?

Comment: please share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: nvm i fixed it. Mesh was just in the wrong group